# use a ggmultiplot object with grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, gridextra

I am trying to use `grid.arrange()` to put a plot of a linear regression and its diagnostic plots into one graph. For the creation of the diagnostic plots I was going to use `autoplot()`

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

linearMod <- lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
qqp <- (autoplot(linearMod, which = 2)) # qqplot
rvf <- (autoplot(linearMod, which = 1)) # res vs fitted plot

grid.arrange(qqp, rvf, nrow = 2)

> Error in `$<-`(`*tmp*`, wrapvp, value = vp) : 
  no method for assigning subsets of this S4 class
```

Apparently, autoplot creates a ggmultiplot of type `S4` and I don't find a way to convert it into a grob, which is needed to use `grid.arrange()`.

I tried:

```
library(ggplotify)
as.grob(qqp)
> Error in UseMethod("as.grob") : 
  no applicable method for 'as.grob' applied to an object of class "ggmultiplot"
as.grob(qqp@plots) # also failed...
```

Does anyone know a solution? May there be any alternative to autoplot's diagnostic plots or any other way to combine it with other plots?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Calling `ggplot2` from `autoplot` class object**

`autoplot` is creating a class object `ggmultiplot` that contain your plot in a ggplot format.

```r
> summary(qqp)
     Length       Class        Mode 
          1 ggmultiplot          S4
```

However, you have to call this `ggplot` in order to be use in `grid.arrange`. With your example, you can do something like that:

```r
library(ggfortify)
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(qqp@plots[[1]], rvf@plots[[1]], nrow = 2)
```

[image]

**Using `ggplot2` to re-create plots made by `autoplot`**

Alternatively, you can extract fitted and residual values using `dplyr` (or something else) and get direct ggplot:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
CARS <- cars[,c("speed","dist")] %>% mutate(Fitted = linearMod$fitted.values, Residual = linearMod$residuals)
a <- ggplot(CARS, aes(x = Fitted, y = Residual))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE)
b <- ggplot(CARS, aes(sample = dist)) + stat_qq() + geom_qq_line(linetype = "dashed")
grid.arrange(b,a, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Hope it helps you to solve your issue